# What is'Id' in POST /sms/v1/messageContact/{id}/send

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobileconnect, sms

I am trying to send a message via rest api. I am unable to understand where do i find the {id} in POST /sms/v1/messageContact/{id}/send.
Where do i find this parameter in mobile connect?

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageList.htm), see if the encoded message id is what is required here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within MobileConnect you can find/setup `Id` by creating a message with **Outbound** type where you have to choose Send Method as `API Trigger`.

- If you're setting up a new message then you can find the `Id` during the Activation phase in a small confirmation window.
- If you're looking to find `Id` of an exisiting Outbound API Trigger then you can view it by selecting the Outbound SMS from MobileConnect overview page.

> Sample URL:
>   https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/`TEST123`/send

Screenshot:

[image]